# what's the difference with the path route: /WEB-INF/ and classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

when I run a springmvc demo I find some demo confige the contextConfigLocation like below

```

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spitter-security.xml
        classpath:service-context.xml
        ...
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

```

So what difference between the path /WEB-INF/ and classpath,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /WEB-INF/ points to the the directory called WEB-INF in the root of the web application.
Whereas the classpath contains /WEB-INF/classes and the JAR files in /WEB-INF/lib.

So the spitter-security lays directly in the web-inf folder, whereas the service-context is in one of the classpath directories.

Comment: if I change /WEB-INF/ spitter-security.xml  TO classpath:spitter-security.xml could it find the spitter-security.xml